# Why is there overflow here?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page with a top menu a right menu and a board in the middle.

see http://jsfiddle.net/pXXNv/

But i keep getting overflow for no obvious reason.

If i remove

```
height:100%;
```

from body html the problem is solved but why is the div bigger then 100% i cant find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case (Since there are only fixed positions) only html needs `height:100%`, not body

```
html { 
    height:100%;
}
body { 
    margin:0px; 
    font-family:Open Sans,helvetica, arial, san-serif; 
    /*background-image:url('achtergrond.png');*/
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color:#ffffff;    
    padding:0px; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pXXNv/2/)**